# Ruby RSpec define before/after hooks for one context only

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following structure of an RSpec test:

```
RSpec.describe A do
  context C1 do
    it EX1a do
    end
    ....
    it EX1n do
    end
  end
  context C2 do
    it EX2a do
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

I would now define a hook, which runs setup and shutdown wordk for the examples within context C1 only. How can I do this? From my understanding [of the structuring of the hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks), using `before(:context)` would be executed once before each context (including C2), while `before(:example)` would be executed once before each example (including EX2a), which is not what I want.

I have RSpec 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly. It depends on where you place the `before` blocks. When you place them inside a context like this

```
RSpec.describe A do
  context C1 do
    before { do_something }

    it EX1a do
    end
    it EX1n do
    end
  end
  context C2 do
    it EX2a do
    end
  end
end
```

then the `before` callback will only be executed before running `EX1a` and `EX1n` but not before `EX2a`.

Similar for `before(:context)` blocks. Quote from the docs: *"`before(:context)` run one time only, before all of the examples in a group"*. A `context` block defines a `group`.

Comment: Great! But what happens if rspec is called with _random_ execution order? From my understanding, this means that Ex2a could be executed between Ex1a and Ex1n. Will RSpec then run my after-hook before the example from context C2 and before entering the next example from context C1?

Comment: The order of groups is randomized in RSpec @user1934428. Which means context C2 content isn't going to be mixed with content in the context C1. As per the docs *Nested groups are always run from top-level to bottom-level in order to avoid
executing before(:context) and after(:context) hooks more than once, but the
order of groups at each level is randomized*.